# Timeout if no response from client using telnet

Tags: php, sockets

i am trying to create a mock mail server and i am having trouble understanding how to timeout my code and close the connection, if their is no response from the client within 1 min.

My current code is this.

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.2:1025", $errno, $errstr); if (!$socket) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)\n";
    die('Could not create socket'); }

set_time_limit(5); while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)){
    while($msg = fread($conn, 1024)){
        echo $msg;
        if (trim($msg) == "quit"){
            fwrite($conn, "220 BYE" . "\n");
            fclose($conn);
            break;
        }
    } }
```

The telnet connection looks like this. (the client)

```
Trying 127.0.0.2...
Connected to 127.0.0.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
stack overflow
if no response within 1 min, i would like the connection to terminate.
quit
220 BYE
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: socket timeout should be sufficient